# How to use Pattern in String replaceAll

Tags: java, regex

I used Pattern as parameter in replaceAll method, I want to remove all characters inside open and close bracket (include bracket characters) however only inside chars was remove, the bracket is still there. Below is my java code

```
String test = "This is my test ( inside the brackets ) and finish here";
String regex = "\\(.*\\)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
String out = test.replaceAll(matcher.group(), "");
System.out.println(out);
```

output is `This is my test () and finish here.`

Answer (score 4):

To use it with a `Pattern` you need to use [**`Matcher#replaceAll`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29) not `String#replaceAll`:

```
String test = "This is my test ( inside the brackets ) and finish here";
String regex = "(?<=\\().*?(?=\\))";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
String out = matcher.replaceAll("");
System.out.println(out);
//=> This is my test () and finish here
```

**PS:** You also needed a change in you regex for your output.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants to get rid of the brackets, too.  See my answer for what I think is going on.

Comment: I thought on same lines then saw this in the question: `output is This is my test () and finish here.`

Answer (score 1):

You can't be getting that result from that code.  If you don't call `find()` on the matcher, you'll get an exception when you call `group()`.  However, if you **do** call `find()` first, `group()` will return the string `( inside the brackets )`, which will be treated as a regex, meaning the brackets will be treated as metacharacters.  So it will match `inside the brackets` (including the leading and trailing spaces, but not the brackets).  That would explain your output.

The fix is to call `matcher.replaceAll("")` instead of `test.replaceAll(matcher.group(), "")`.  And don't bother calling `matcher.find()`.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
String test = "This is my test ( inside the brackets ) and finish here";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", ""));
```

First argument of `String.replaceAll()` is a regex

Comment: Actually, I want to build the regex automatically, so I cannot put as parameter